# How to add x months to a date based on an integerfield in django with mysql

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, mariadb

I would like to know how to achieve the following MariaDB-Syntax using django's query expressions:

```
select distinct CASE
    when (`coredb_commoncontract`.`duration_month` is not null)
         then (`coredb_commoncontract`.`date_start` + INTERVAL `coredb_commoncontract`.`duration_month` MONTH)
    else null
end as `date_end`
from `coredb_commoncontract`
```

The duration of a contact is given as an integer in CommonContract.duration_month.
I am trying to calculate the end date in an annotation.

EDIT: the part I am having problems with is

```sql
... INTERVAL `coredb_commoncontract`.`duration_month` MONTH
```

EDIT 2:
The python solution should look something like this:

```py
    qs.annotate(
            date_end=Case(
                When(
                    Q(date_termination__isnull=True) & Q(duration_month__isnull=False),
                    then=F('date_start') + coredb_expressions.Interval(F('duration_month'), Value('MONTH'))
                ),
                When(Q(date_termination__isnull=True) & Q(duration_month__isnull=True), then=Value(None)),
                When(Q(date_termination__isnull=False), then=F('date_termination')),
                default=Value(None),
                output_field=models.DateField(),
            ),
```

that `Interval` is currently simply a subclass of `django.db.models.Func`, but it doesn't work and I'm unsure how to correct it.

expressions.py:

````py
class Interval(Func):
    """
    ### Interval(models.expressions.Func)
    Represents an interval of time.

    #### Usage:
    ```python
    Interval(<value-expression>, <unit-name-expression>)
    ```

    #### Example:
    ```python
    Interval(models.F('duration_month'), models.Value('MONTH'))
    ```

    #### Resulting SQL:
    ```sql
    INTERVAL(`coredb_commoncontract`.`duration_month`, 'MONTH')
    ```

    #### Requirements:
    - The database must accept the syntax given above.
    - Known compatible databases: MariaDB
    """
    function = 'INTERVAL'
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this hacky solution which seems to work as I want it.

```py
class Interval(Func):
    function = 'INTERVAL'
    template = 'INTERVAL %(expressions)s UNIT'
    arg_joiner = ' '

    def __init__(self, *args, unit='MONTH', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.template = self.template.replace('UNIT', unit)

    def as_sql(self, *a, **kw):
        # TODO: BAD HACK!
        result, _ = super().as_sql(*a, **kw)
        result: str
        return (result.replace('%s', ''), [])
```

Answer (score -1):

You're almost there.

You don't really need `CASE`, and you forgot `DATE_ADD`:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(
    `coredb_commoncontract`.`date_start`,
    INTERVAL `coredb_commoncontract`.`duration_month` MONTH
) AS `date_end`
FROM `coredb_commoncontract`
```

Comment: How do I achieve that with django's query expressions? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/

Comment: @SMoenig, I'd sugget you adding `end_date` as a genrated column to your table. So you'd not have overhead in jango =))

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. That is in fact the solution I am currently using. I was asking out of curiosity.